# Kafka connection issue when broker is in different Kubernetes namespace

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I have a Node.js microservice connecting to a Kafka service. If the Kafka broker is in the default namespace with the other microservices, there are no issues.

```
const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  // brokers: ['kafka-broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092'],
  brokers: ['kafka-broker-srv:9092'],
})

const admin = kafka.admin()
    await admin.connect()
    console.log('admin connected')
    console.log('TOPICS', await admin.listTopics())
```

```
[auth-pod] admin connected
[auth-pod] TOPICS [ 'test-topic' ]
```

Here is the Kubernetes configuration:

```
# create namespace
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: "kafka"
  labels:
    name: "kafka"
---
# create zookeeper service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-service
  name: zookeeper-service
  # namespace: kafka
spec:
  # type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: zookeeper-port
      port: 2181
      # nodePort: 30181
      targetPort: 2181
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper
  name: zookeeper
  # namespace: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: zookeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
---
# deploy kafka broker
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # labels:
  #   app: kafka-broker
  name: kafka-broker-srv
  # namespace: kafka
spec:
  # headless service
  clusterIP: "None"
  ports:
  - name: foo
    port: 9092
  selector:
    app: kafka-broker
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-broker
  name: kafka-broker
  # namespace: kafka
spec:
  # replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-broker
    spec:
      hostname: kafka-broker
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
          value: "1"
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zookeeper-service:2181
        - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
          value: PLAINTEXT://:9092
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: PLAINTEXT://kafka-broker:9092
          # automatically create topics
        - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
          value: 'test-topic:1:1'
        - name: KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE
          value: 'true'
        - name: KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE
          value: 'true'
        image: wurstmeister/kafka
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kafka-broker
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
```

However, if it is in a separate namespace, I can connect to the service `'kafka-broker-srv.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092'` that is in the kafka namespace, but I get a `KafkaJSBrokerNotFound` error.

```
[auth-pod] admin connected
[auth-pod] KafkaJSNonRetriableError
[auth-pod]   Caused by: KafkaJSBrokerNotFound: No brokers in the broker pool
[auth-pod]     at BrokerPool.withBroker (/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/cluster/brokerPool.js:270:13)
[auth-pod]     ... 3 lines matching cause stack trace ...
[auth-pod]     at async test (/app/src/kakfka/connect.js:18:27) {
[auth-pod]   name: 'KafkaJSNumberOfRetriesExceeded',
[auth-pod]   retriable: false,
[auth-pod]   helpUrl: undefined,
[auth-pod]   retryCount: 5,
[auth-pod]   retryTime: 12820,
[auth-pod]   [cause]: KafkaJSBrokerNotFound: No brokers in the broker pool
[auth-pod]       at BrokerPool.withBroker (/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/cluster/brokerPool.js:270:13)
[auth-pod]       at /app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/cluster/index.js:191:32
[auth-pod]       at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[auth-pod]       at async Object.listTopics (/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/admin/index.js:103:31)
[auth-pod]       at async test (/app/src/kakfka/connect.js:18:27) {
[auth-pod]     retriable: true,
[auth-pod]     helpUrl: undefined,
[auth-pod]     [cause]: undefined
[auth-pod]   }
[auth-pod] }
```

I don't see what the issue could be since it worked before and the only thing that would need to change is to specify the namespace to connect to the service `.kafka.svc.cluster.local`.

If I use the same name for the service and the broker `'kafka-broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092'` (I thought I wasn't supposed to use difference names), I get a connection timeout.

```
[auth-pod] admin connected
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:11:57.662Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:11:59.139Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:00.351Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:02.154Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:02.958Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app","stack":"Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:03.230Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:05.359Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:05.461Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app","stack":"Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:06.533Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:09.139Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app","stack":"Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:09.640Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:10.646Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:11.536Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app","stack":"Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:15.262Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app","stack":"Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:16.151Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:17.160Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app"}
[auth-pod] KafkaJSNonRetriableError
[auth-pod]   Caused by: KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection timeout
[auth-pod]     at Timeout.onTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connection.js:223:23)
[auth-pod]     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
[auth-pod]     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
[auth-pod]   name: 'KafkaJSNumberOfRetriesExceeded',
[auth-pod]   retriable: false,
[auth-pod]   helpUrl: undefined,
[auth-pod]   retryCount: 5,
[auth-pod]   retryTime: 10402,
[auth-pod]   [cause]: KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection timeout
[auth-pod]       at Timeout.onTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connection.js:223:23)
[auth-pod]       at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
[auth-pod]       at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
[auth-pod]     retriable: true,
[auth-pod]     helpUrl: undefined,
[auth-pod]     broker: 'kafka-broker:9092',
[auth-pod]     code: undefined,
[auth-pod]     [cause]: undefined
[auth-pod]   }
[auth-pod] }
[auth-pod] {"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-03-28T04:12:17.548Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker","broker":"kafka-broker:9092","clientId":"my-app","stack":"Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN kafka-broker\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)"}
```

The same thing happens with producers and consumers, the `connect` call works, but not the subsequent methods.

```
// producer
const producer = kafka.producer()
await producer.connect()
console.log('producer connected', producer)
send
await producer.send({
  topic: 'test-topic',
  messages: [{ value: 'Hello KafkaJS user!' }],
})
// await producer.disconnect()

// consumer
const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'test-group' })
await consumer.connect()
console.log('consumer connected', consumer)
// receive
await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'test-topic', fromBeginning: true })
await consumer.run({
  eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
    console.log('CONSUME', {
      value: message.value.toString(),
    })
  },
})
```

I am not sure why the naming of the service would make a difference.

Given that I can connect to the service and that the dns resolution is the same within any namespace (so I doubt I would need to change any names in the kafka configuration), what could cause these errors? [full code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/microservices-quiz-app/tree/f63eb96696683cdb7276203ea5c2e32280d1f1db)

---

Interestingly, if I deploy to both namespaces and connect to the service in the kafka namespace, it does work.

```
  brokers: ['kafka-broker-srv.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092'],
```

```
[auth-pod] admin connected
[auth-pod] TOPICS [ 'test-topic' ]
```

Is kafkajs connecting to the broker in the default namespace directly; if so, what is the point of going through the kafka service (in the kafka namespace)?

Edit:
Since I am using a headless service, the phrasing "going through the kafka service" probably doesn't make sense. The service name is resolved to the ip of the pod directly. If `connect` works, does that mean the connection to the pod succeeded; if there is a connection error for subsequent method calls, is kafkajs connecting to something other than the pod?

Comment: As answered before, why are you continuing to use `wurstmeister/*` Docker images instead of Strimzi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set this

```
- name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
  value: PLAINTEXT://kafka-broker:9092
```

This means that **after** a client connects via the bootstrap protocol (when given the FQDN), it sees **this** address (and not your headless service), not the value you provided in the app code.
This has no reference to any namespace, therefore will try to lookup `tcp://kafka-broker.default.svc.cluster.local:9092` (assuming your app is in the `default` namespace).

For more details, refer [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)

As [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75844920/2308683), you need to advertise the FQDN / address of that *specific* Kafka pod, so that clients can connect directly to exact brokers, and not to a Service address that is round-robin / load-balanced. For example, Strimzi or Bitnami Helm Charts will advertise values like `kafka-0` and `kafka-1` for a two-node cluster, while still maintaining some `kafka-svc` Headless Service to use for bootstrapping.

---

> if I deploy to both namespaces and connect to the service in the kafka namespace, it does work

Because that is [how DNS lookups are supposed to work](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).

Answer (score 0):

I thought the Kafka pod was connecting to something else within its namespace, but I simply misunderstood [why](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/) we need to provide the full connection string `kafka-broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local` in KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS as well.

> The key thing is that when you run a client, the broker you pass to it
> is just where it’s going to go and get the metadata about brokers in
> the cluster from. The actual host and IP that it will connect to for
> reading/writing data is based on the data that the broker passes back
> in that initial connection—even if it’s just a single node and the
> broker returned is the same as the one it’s connected to.

I am still not sure why there were 2 different errors though.